# Excel macro - combinig two macros to "one button"

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macros setted up to work with clipboard and i want to combine them to "one click" button in my excel. I'm very new to excel macros and any kind of help is much appriciated.

Macro 1 - It copies set text to clipboard

```
Function Clipboard(Optional StoreText As String) As String
'PURPOSE: Read/Write to Clipboard
'Source: ExcelHero.com (Daniel Ferry)

Dim x As Variant

'Store as variant for 64-bit VBA support
  x = StoreText

'Create HTMLFile Object
  With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
      Select Case True
        Case Len(StoreText)
          'Write to the clipboard
            .setData "text", x
        Case Else
          'Read from the clipboard (no variable passed through)
            Clipboard = .GetData("text")
      End Select
    End With
  End With

End Function

Sub Click_to_Clip()

'Copy text to the clipboard
  Clipboard "makes my happy!"

'To read text from the clipboard:
  'MsgBox Clipboard
  
End Sub
```

Macro 2 - it copies text from clipboard

```
Sub Click_from_Clipboard()
'This works only with text!
  Dim oData As Object

  'New MSForms.DataObject with guid and late binding
  Set oData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

  'Get text from clipboard
  'to the DataObject
  oData.GetFromClipboard

  'Show text
  MsgBox oData.GetText
End Sub
```

What I want is to for eg. copie a word "Cake" from www (Ctrc+c to clipboard) then click "button" in excel and   then ctrl+v on word document and get a sentance "Cake makes me happy". ("Cake" from www page, "makes me happy" predefind in macro 1).

Can you offer any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had all the pieces there already, I just combined them for you.

```vb
Sub Click_to_Clip()
    
    Clipboard " makes my happy!"
    
End Sub

Sub Clipboard(Optional StoreText As String)
'PURPOSE: Read/Write to Clipboard

    Dim x As Variant, oldCB As Object, oldText As String
    
    Set oldCB = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    oldCB.GetFromClipboard
    oldText = oldCB.GetText

    'Store as variant for 64-bit VBA support
    x = oldText & StoreText
    
    CreateObject("htmlfile").parentWindow.clipboardData.setData "text", x

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a alot!